# How to improve performance of my Joomla based Intranet system?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, joomla, intranet

I have a Joomla 1.5.10 based Intranet system. In this application, we have more than 80% custom extensions. Below is the configuration:

```
Apache version :    Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8
PHP version :   5.3.13
MySQL version : mysqlnd 5.1.11
```

It has 3 dedicated Appliocation Server which configuration is :

```
Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 2
Compiler:   MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Architecture:   x86
```

Again, it has dedicated DB server which configuration is :

```
 8x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5460 @3.16GHz, 8.0GB RAM, Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 2.
```

Below is the MySQL settings in my system:

```
Sl.#    Parameter           Value
1   Key Buffer          547M
2   Sort Buffer Size    256K
3   Query cache limit   4M
4   Cache size          350M
5   Long query time         5
6   Interactive timeout 300
7   Max Connection          800
8   Thread cache size   36
```

We have configured WAMPSERVER (32 BITS & PHP 5.3) 2.2E on our servers and then install MySQL5.1 on other dedicated server. Hence, we are not using MySQL provided with WAMP.
My system become too slow or crash when number of DB connection threads crossed 100. Number of logged-in users we can see are 3000-5000 only. Multiple queries start logging in the slow query logs and huge number of queries are in sleep state. Those queries which are running normal also start logging in slow query log and taking much time in execution.
I am unable to find the bottlenecks in my system. Is there Joomla or MySQL creating bottlenecks. Would upgrade helpful to avoid the bottlenecks and increased the performance of our system? If yes, what should we upgrade - Joomla or MySQL and what will be the strategy to upgrade the system. Is there a known performance/scalability issue in 1.5.10 that is resolved by an upgrade?

My overall goal is to increase the system performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Joomla 1.5.10? Seriously? At least update to Joomla 1.5.26 or even better, upgrade to 2.5 or 3.2

Comment: What performance improvement I will get by upgrading to 1.5.26? We have a lot of custom extensions. Is there a known performance/scalability issue in 1.5.10 that is resolved by an upgrade.

Comment: Well put is this way, you're 16 versions behind 1.5.26. During this time, a lot of bugs and security issues were fixed. Bug fixes can sometimes increase performance. Upgrading won't harm your custom extensions. Do also note that even though it's a big step, upgrading to Joomla 3.2 will increase performance. It could simply be sue to the fact that the custom extensions have been badly coded which would explain the poor performance.

Comment: Thanks @Lodder. When we searched the benefits of newer version of joomla, maximum benefits are related with feature enhancement like UI enhancement, more user friendly features, search, responsive design support, ACL enhancement etc. only. There is no such information related with performance improvement. Since, we have already implemented our own component for ACL, search, content management. So, newer features are not important for us. Is there any architecture based enhancement done by Joomla in their newer version which can improve our performance?

Comment: @ursitesion: A cms upgrade most likley break something.

Comment: going to write a full answer, will make life easier

Answer (score 2):

First of all as mentioned in my comments, upgrading your CMS to atleast Joomla 1.5.26 will help. You're running PHP 5.3 and only Joomla 1.5.15+ is fully compatible with this PHP version. Seeing as you're using 1.5.10, there will be some issues there.

Apache is not an issue here. There are sites out there running Joomla that have thousands of users and run Aache without any problems, so not to worry about this.

From Joomla 1.6 onwards, the optimization started. Reduced and sorted database tables, endless bug fixes and also security issues. The framework has also improved majorly not to mention it supports PDO, mysqli (more secure than mysql) and postgre. Ugrading to Joomla 3.2 (latest version) will be of course a massive step. You will have to make all your custom extensions compatible with the new Joomla version and keep up to date with the latest coding standards. Even though this is a big step and will of course take some time, it's fully worth it. Joomla 1.5 hasn't been supported for a long time now and things are moving forward majorly.

Your server specs are good, you're running a decent PHP and Apache version, you're MySQL version could be upgraded however it's still not bad. So overall, it's not a server related issue.

I do think that it could very well be the way your custom extensions have been coded. So my final suggest would simply be taking a backup of your site and start migrating it and all of your extensions to Joomla 3.2.

Comment: Can we directly migrate 1.5.10 system to 3.2? It will require a complete rewrite of the system.

Comment: You will first need to upgrade to 1.5.26 so the next migration goes smoothly. Once done have a read of [this](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Migrating_from_Joomla_1.5_to_Joomla_2.5) which shows you how to upgrade to 2.5 and from then on, upgrading to 3.2 will be a 1 click update in the backend. Do note that this will **not** update your custom extensions. You will need to do this manually

Comment: Thanks @Lodder. We have changed in our code as per the changes in PHP 5.3 version. Joomla upgrade will require a complete rewrite of the system. Our Intranet system is too huge and you can imagine it by the number of tables used in this system - 241. To do this, we require enough time. But, we need to improve the performance of Intranet ASAP. Will Upgrading MySQL from 5.1 to 5.5 be helpful? It will take lesser time than upgrading Joomla.

Comment: @lodder if you doubt that the problem is with custom extensions code, how much the joomla upgrade will actually help. It can be very probable that even after upgrade some of the badly coded custom extension is giving trouble.

Comment: Upgrading from MySQL 5.1 to 5.5 won't really make much difference. There isn't really anything server related you can do. As stated in my answer, it's most likely your custom extensions causing the problem. If migrating to Joomla 3.2 will take too much time, then atleast update to Joomla 1.5.26 as your current version has isn't fully compatible with PHP 5.3

Comment: @sushilbharwani - Upgrading to Joomla 3.2 of course won't fix the custom extensions issues, however as a CMS side of view, then performance is better. The custom extensions will manually have to be upgraded.

Comment: @Lodder: We have changed our whole system code (including Joomla library and all types of extensions) according to PHP 5.3. When we get performance hit during high traffic, we found that number of DB connection threads varies between 100-250. There are some specific set of SQL queries which are logging regularly in slow query log. Also, there is a lot of SQL queries in sleep state. This is the main reason for focusing on MYSQL upgrade to use the advanced features of MySQL. Hoping that new features of MySQL would help in optimization of queries. Please suggest.

Comment: If you have changed the while system and have pyrposely used a lot of database queries then I cant really suggest anything else. Without actually see the code for you custom extensions its so hard to tell. Try taking a backup of the website and putting it on a localhost such as wampserver to see if its still slow.

Comment: Is there any evidence that upgrading Joomla will improve the system performance? Has Joomla made any major changes in architecture or database pooling? I will try to decide my strategy on the basis of this.

Comment: Yes, they have made major changes since 1.5. Do some research and see what has been changed.

Comment: Joomla has been improved at the cache level. Also, they have implemented multiple ways to decrease the page load timing. Use the MVC in more appropriate way. But, I did not find any evidence of architecture level or database level improvement.

Comment: It's not file and folder architecture improvements that have been made, it's code related improvements. As for the database, install a copy of Joomla 3.2 somewhere and compare the database tables to a fresh copy of 1.5. Not to mention HMVC is now possible using the FOF framework. Read the third paragraph of [this](http://www.cmscritic.com/joomla-3.2-released-with-record-number-of-new-features/#.Uo4LMeJ_Dp8). Anyway, upgrading to Joomla 3.2 will not simply solve the problem on it's own, like I have said before, it's most likely your custom extensions using poor code. So the choice is up to you

Answer (score 0):

You can change the webserver. Apache is totally bloat. Lighttpd can help to fix the problem. It' also simpler to run. A cms upgrade most likely break something.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Apache being used to run Joomla. Not sure on the exact stats but I would say that the majority of Joomla hosted sites run Apache.

Comment: @Lodder:It's too complicated.

Comment: Yes, I agree, Apache is much more complex, however judging by the OP's server specs, Apache is not the problem here. 80% of the extensions are custom + he's using an absolute ancient version of Joomla therefore it's buggy and the extensions are most likely coded badly.

Comment: @Phpdna: Providing configuration variables for APACHE for better performance will be a great help. Miss-configuration of Apache might be a reason of slow performance. We can't switch to Lighttpd so easily. Stick with Apache is more recommended.